# Entity Framework Table Classes aren't being saved to source control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, edmx

[image]

Notice that the files PersonalAlert and PersonalReport do not have the padlock indicating that the code is checked in to source control.  I can't figure out how to add these files to source control.  This is a problem when I am sharing a codebase with some remote developers, and they do not get these files.

These files are created by Model1.tt automatically.

For bonus points, tell me how to recreate these classes on demand.  I have tried clicking on Model1.tt and choosing 'Run Custom Tool', but that did not work for me.